# Add sbt plugins to Eclipse scala-ide

Tags: sbt, scala-ide, sbteclipse

I have scala project that I use sbt to manage and I have a sbt plugin ([sbt-twirl](https://github.com/spray/twirl#readme) to be specific) that I need for the project. Now I would like to use Eclipse for editing/debugging the project. As usual, I used sbt-eclipse to generate the Eclipse project files and use scala-ide plugin in Eclipse. However, the Eclipse project does not compile the code that requires the sbt-twirl plugin. I am guessing that the sbt used by Eclipse is not picking up the sbt-twirl plugin. Is there any way to configure Eclipse's sbt to use the sbt-twirl plugin (configure either automatically through sbt-eclipse, or manually in Eclipse)?

I am using Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) with Scala IDE 2.0.2 .

Thanks in advance.